# paddingheight does different heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a website but i have a problem
When i press different images that it goes to a different panel. The site above the panel and the URL bar becomes bigger. but i want it to be fixed to like 100 PX

Right now i have this

```
$body._resize = function() {
    var factor = ($window.width() * $window.height()) / (1440 * 900);
    $body.css('font-size', Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(factor * settings.sizeFactor), settings.sizeMin), settings.sizeMax) + 'pt');
    $main.height(panels[activePanelId].outerHeight());
    $body._reposition();
};

$body._reposition = function() {
    if (skel.vars.isTouch && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180))
        $wrapper.css('padding-top', Math.max((($window.height() - (panels[activePanelId].outerHeight() + $footer.outerHeight())) / 2) - $nav.height(), 30) + 'px');
    else
        $wrapper.css('padding-top', ((($window.height() - panels[firstPanelId].height()) / 2) - $nav.height()) + 'px');
};
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: That is JS and not only CSS right?

Comment: whoops yes i need to add a tag sorry

Comment: Could you try to get this into JSFiddle please?

Comment: you can check it out on my own site www.sandergouman.nl When you press the different buttons that are there you see that the white is going down

Comment: what do you want to achieve with resetting the padding-top? Couldn´t you just add an empty div above with a fixed hight of 100px?

Comment: i dont know how? so it is always just 100 px for example from the top

Comment: Why are you changing `$wrapper.css('padding-top')` why not just leave it? Try removing the `$body._reposition` function's contents

Comment: you could always use the "ugly" `!important` added to your `wrapper`: `#wrapper {padding-top:100px !important}`but obviously it would be better to fix your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to completely asses your code because I can not see the html and css.  The problem might have to do with the positions of your html elements. Sometimes when html element have a position of relative, padding from another element can throw it off due to the change in position. I think it might just be easier to make a blank div above it and set the height to 100px. Good luck.